# Do you need to learn ExpressJS first before learning FeathersJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, feathersjs

I'm quite new to the world of NodeJS and JS.

Do I need to learn ExpressJS first before learning FeathersJS?

I read some post that FeathersJS is a drop-in-replacement for Express, so does this mean that I can start with FeathersJS first?

Comment: I dont think so.

Comment: @Naramsim I don't have a problem with a code, I'm asking a question regarding ExpressJS and FeathersJS. :)

Comment: Feathers is a wrapper over Express which means you would probably miss some important details if you don't understand how express (including its routing etc.) works.

Comment: @WiktorZychla so it would be recommended to learn ExpressJS first before learning FeathersJS?

Comment: Yeah, and this is not the place

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to learn Express before learning Feathers. As it says on the stack overflow feathers tag page (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/feathersjs/info): "Feathers is a library that extends Express."

As you learn more about Feathers you may want to learn some of the components of Express. But **my recommendation is to go start with the Feathers guides** (https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/readme.html). You will pick up what you need about Express as you go.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It can help to better understand how things work, assuming you are using FeathersJS with Express. But, it’s not a requirement. You can accomplish quite a lot simply by know FeathersJS and leaving @feathers-express to do it’s own thing.